# min-GW gcc cant link winsock2.h

Tags: c, c99, winsock2, open62541

I'm trying to use winsock2 library, i'm using it to compile tutorial server from [open62541](https://github.com/open62541/open62541)

some code that i used  and make error (from open62541.c that built from amalgamation):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#INCLUDE <ws2tcpip.h>

int main(){
   struct pollfd tmp_poll_fd;
   }
```

i'm using mingw to compile the open62541 server, and follow the [tutorial](https://www.open62541.org/doc/1.2/tutorial_server_firststeps.html)

```
gcc -std=c99 server.c open62541.c -lws2_32 -o server.exe
```

the error :

```
error: storage size of 'tmp_poll_fd' isn't known
     struct pollfd tmp_poll_fd;
```

the other error also related to winsock2 library such as `POLLWRNORM undeclared`

i already check that winsock2.h is in the place,

and i also check the inside to winsock2.h contain `struct pollfd` and `POLLWRNORM`

i already try some change in gcc command such as :

```
gcc -std=c99 server.c open62541.c -libws2_32 -o server.exe
```

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Include ``Windows.h`` *before* ``winsock2.h``

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn still same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer is based on my locally installed version of MinGW (8.1.0, built by MinGW-W64 project), it can be a different situation on yours.*

The include file "winsock2.h" has a guard on the target Windows version:

```c
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)

/* ... */

typedef struct pollfd {

/* ... */

#endif /*(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)*/
```

The macro `_WIN32_WINNT` is set by "_mingw.h" to 0x502, if you don't change it by other means:

```c
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x502
#endif
```

The value 0x502 means "Windows Server 2003" according to [Microsoft's document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-170). If you set the macro to a value greater than or equal to 0x600 ("Windows Vista"), your compile will succeed:

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x600

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

int main(void) {
    struct pollfd tmp_poll_fd;
}
```